# When we use "could" to say there is a possibility, do we change the tense in the subordinate clause?

Tags: modal-verbs

"Could" can be used to say something is a possibility, which has a similar meaning to that of "might." The tense in the subordinate clause after "might" doesn't change. But when we use "could" in this sense, do we change the tense in the subordinate clause?

**Example 1**

The tense in the subordinate clause remains unchanged.

> He has been doing lots of math recently. He might think that he will get good grades on the math exam tomorrow.

**Example 2**

What tense do we use when we use could here?

> He has been doing lots of math recently. He could think that he **will/would** get good grades on the math exam tomorrow.

Comment: will in both cases. But **bear this in mind**: He could/might think that he **would get** good grades **if he studied harder**. Maybe this should be an answer...

Comment: Perhaps you're being misled by ***could*** in the second example, which can be used for both ***current*** and ***future*** possibilities. Compare *He could be dead* (now) and *He could die* (in the future). In your example, it seems to me that if we interpret ***he could think** [something]* as referring to what he might think ***now***, the relevant thought is that he ***will*** do well *(if he **studies** hard)*. But if we interpret ***could*** as referring to what he might think ***tomorrow*** (which is hypothetical irrealis "not present"), he ***would*** do well if he ***studied*** hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're being misled by the fact that in some circumstances *could* functions as a past.

Historically, *could* was the past of *can* (and *might* was the past of *may*, incidentally). This still appears when we back-shift for indirect quotation:

> He said "I can do it" -> He said he could do it.

But in modern English, as you note, *could* has other senses, expressing possibility or uncertainty. In these senses there's no past tense involved, and so no reason to alter the tense of the embedded sentence.